# Issues trying to use mmh3 in jupiter notebook

Tags: python, hash, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use import and use mmh3 for hashing however I get errors when I try to do so. 
These are the error i get:

Collecting mmh3
  Using cached mmh3-2.5.1.tar.gz (9.8 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mmh3*emphasized text*
  Building wheel for mmh3 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /PYSPARK-ENV/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vr4gj2gj
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'mmh3' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c mmh3module.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mmh3module.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for mmh3
  Running setup.py clean for mmh3
Failed to build mmh3
Installing collected packages: mmh3
    Running setup.py install for mmh3 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /PYSPARK-ENV/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-rvdzd4bs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /PYSPARK-ENV/include/site/python3.6/mmh3
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'mmh3' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c mmh3module.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mmh3module.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /PYSPARK-ENV/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6vdrtr2d/mmh3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-rvdzd4bs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /PYSPARK-ENV/include/site/python3.6/mmh3 Check the logs for full command output.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Then if I try and just import it, it will say mmh3 not found

Even though it all works on my local machine

Any help would be greatly appreciated.